# Is there a way to train neural network in C#, UWP?

Tags: uwp, neural-network

As I understand, Windows ML can be used in UWP to evaluate pre-trained neural network models, that are downloaded in ONNX format.

My task is to train neural network from scratch with user's data (images) in UWP application, and then use it (in the same app).

I suppose this is not possible, but maybe it is? If yes - I would be glad to get a url/sample or something. If not, are there any good nuget packages to do this in UWP (C#)?

I'm going to use some sort of simple neural network with several layers.

Would appreciate your thoughts and help..

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to train neural network in C#, UWP?

The answer is **Yes**. But please note:

***Windows ML is a preview feature which may be substantially modified before it’s officially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.***

> My task is to train neural network from scratch with user's data (images) in UWP application, and then use it (in the same app).

Windows ML supports the v1.0 release of the ONNX format, see [ONNX Models](https://github.com/onnx/models) on GitHub.

To learn how to train an ONNX model with Visual Studio Tools for AI, see [Train a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/machine-learning/train-ai-model).

You also could get the [Windows Machine Learning UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning) from github.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. However, I couldn't find any way, hint or sample on how to train a neural network in UWP (in runtime)... It is quite easy to add ONNX file to project and use it, but one has to train the network before adding to UWP project, in Visual Studio environment, unfortunately, as I see it.

Comment: I think that would need [Visual Studio Tools for AI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/train-model-vs-tools-ai#install-visual-studio-tools-for-ai)

Answer (score 0):

There is also this TechNet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36428.basis-of-neural-networks-in-c.aspx#Train_Function article that has some implementations on training.